# What's the meaning of "would" in this sentence?

Tags: usage, modal-verbs, irrealis-mood, would

Could you explain Damian's use of "would" when he answers a someone's question in the following? I can't understand the meaning.

> **Dwi**: What does "emphatic" means in this sentence?
>
> > *An emphatic kick from the Lepzig man, who thumps his kick right-footed and into the net to the left of goal*.
>
> **Damian**: "Emphatic" in this example means to hit the ball with real force (very hard indeed). An "emphatic finish" **would be** a goal scored with a hard shot. An "emphatic win" **would be** a very good win when one team has easily defeated the other team (maybe by a big score).

Comment: Damian gives examples that don't exist, but they might exist in the future. An "emphatic finish" **would be** [if it ever happens at all] a goal scored with a hard shot."

Comment: It’s idiomatic and in this usage is pretty much synonymous with “an emphatic finish **is**…”

Comment: I think "would" implies "a polite expression of an opinion".

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Would have + past participle" construction can be used to express speculation about the past?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21161/would-have-past-participle-construction-can-be-used-to-express-speculation-a)

Comment: @YosefBaskin So if something doesn't exist, do you use "would?"

Comment: @PaulTanenbau "Would" can be replace by "is". Isn't there any difference?

Comment: Only the slightest of differences. Another paraphrase that may further illustrate the sense of the expression (and what the *would* is doing) is, “I **would** use the term ‘an emphatic finish’ to describe a goal scored with a hard shot.”

Comment: @gotube answer explains it. *Would* has variable meaning.

Answer (score 1):

One function of "would" is to indicate *hypothetical* or otherwise *unreal* situations in the present or future.

In your context, "would" is used to indicate an hypothetical goal and an hypothetical win. They could be reworded like this in the so-called "second conditional", which you're hopefully familiar with:

> If there was a goal described as "an emphatic finish", it would be one scored with a hard shot.
>
> If there was a win described as "emphatic", it would be a very good win when one team has easily defeated the other team (maybe by a big score)